# How to set max sequence length with a hugging face sagemaker estimator?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers

I'd like to increase the max sequence length from 128 to 512 (the maximum [distilbert](https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased) can handle.) I believe it's only using 128 tokens right now, because the training samples it prints out have an attention_mask with 128 values. This is my code:

```
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFace

# gets role for executing training job
role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
hyperparameters = {
    'model_name_or_path': 'distilbert-base-uncased',
    'output_dir': '/opt/ml/model',
    'do_predict': True,
    'do_eval': True,
    'do_train': True,
    "train_file": "/opt/ml/input/data/train/train.csv",
    "validation_file": "/opt/ml/input/data/val/val.csv",
    "test_file": "/opt/ml/input/data/test/test.csv",
    "num_train_epochs": 50,
    "per_device_train_batch_size": 32
}

# git configuration to download our fine-tuning script
git_config = {'repo': 'https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git','branch': 'v4.6.1'}

# creates Hugging Face estimator
huggingface_estimator = HuggingFace(
    entry_point='run_glue.py',
    source_dir='./examples/pytorch/text-classification',
    instance_type='ml.p3.8xlarge',
    instance_count=1,
    role=role,
    git_config=git_config,
    transformers_version='4.6.1',
    pytorch_version='1.7.1',
    py_version='py36',
    #use_spot_instances = True,
    #max_wait = 24*60*60+1,
    hyperparameters = hyperparameters
)

# starting the train job
huggingface_estimator.fit({'train' : s3_input + "/train.csv",
                           'val' : s3_input + "/val.csv",
                           'test' : s3_input + "/test.csv"})
```

Inspecting run_glue.py, input arguments are taken [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.6.1/examples/pytorch/text-classification/run_glue.py#L186)

```
model_args, data_args, training_args = parser.parse_json_file(json_file=os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1]))
```

but the hyperparameters that we can [set](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.6.1/src/transformers/training_args.py) only impact training_args. data_args gets used to set the max_seq_length [later](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.6.1/examples/pytorch/text-classification/run_glue.py#L367) in this file. I don't see an option in the [huggingface estimator](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/huggingface/sagemaker.huggingface.html#hugging-face-estimator) to pass anything other than hyperparameters. I could fork v4.6.1 and manually set this value, but it seems overkill, is there a proper way to just pass this value?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `max_seq_length : 512` can just be plugged into the hyperparams. I likely typo'd this before as I was getting messages that the param wasn't being used.